# error: prototype for does not match any in class

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error and I cannot see what is wrong, I'm new to c++.

The error is

> "error: prototype for 'void my_payroll::display_payslip(float, float, float, float)' does not match any in class 'my_payroll'|"

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>


class my_payroll
{
public: 
float get_gross(float hours, float rate);
float paye_method (float gross);
float usc_method (float gross);
float prsi(float gross); 
void display_payslip (float gross, float hours, float rate);

`private: 
float dm_hours;
float dm_rate;
float dm_gross;
float dm_paye;
float dm_usc;
float dm_prsi;
float dm_netpay;
};


float my_payroll::get_gross(float hours, float rate)
{
dm_hours = hours;
dm_rate = rate;
return (dm_hours * dm_rate);
}

float my_payroll::paye_method(float gross)
{
dm_gross = gross;
if (dm_gross <= 630.77)
{dm_paye = dm_gross * .2;}
if (dm_gross > 630.77)
{dm_paye = ((dm_gross - 630.77) * 41) + 126.15;}
return dm_paye;
}

float my_payroll::usc_method(float gross)
{
dm_gross = gross;
if (dm_gross <= 193)
{dm_usc = dm_gross * .02;}
if (dm_gross > 308)
{dm_usc = ((dm_gross - 308) *.07) +8.46;}
if (dm_gross > 193 && dm_gross <= 308)
{dm_usc = ((dm_gross - 193) *04) + 3.86;}
return dm_usc;

}    
float my_payroll::prsi(float gross)
{
dm_gross = gross;
dm_prsi = (dm_gross * .02 ); 
return dm_prsi;
}


void my_payroll::display_payslip(float gross, float hours, float rate, float              netpay) > this is the line that I'm getting the error on
{
dm_hours = hours;
dm_netpay = netpay;
dm_rate = rate;
dm_gross = gross;
dm_netpay = (dm_gross - dm_usc - dm_paye - dm_prsi);
return;
cout << "*****************************" << endl;
cout << "\t Gross Pay " << gross<< endl;
cout << "\t prsi " << prsi << endl;
cout << "\t paye " << paye<< endl;
cout << "\t usc " << usc << endl;
cout << "\t Net " << netpay << endl;
cout << "*****************************" << endl;

}





float hours, rate;
float gross;
float paye;
float usc;
float prsi;
float netpay;


int main()

{
cout << "Key in hours worked "  << endl;
cin >> hours;
cout << "Key in hourly rate " << endl;
cin >> rate;
]

class my_payroll payroll_object;

gross = payroll_object.get_gross(hours,rate);
paye = payroll_object.paye_method(gross);
usc = payroll_object.usc_method(gross);
prsi = payroll_object.prsi(gross);
payroll_object.display_payslip(gross);
```

Comment: The error says exactly what's wrong. Read it.

Comment: Also, you have crippled yourself with terrible indentation and line breaking, making it very hard to read the code and put the error message in context. Don't do that to yourself. Keep everything clean and format with method and sense, and you'll be in a much better position to learn and improve.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I will try and figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Inside the class definition there is declared member function `display_payslip` that has three parameters

```
void display_payslip (float gross, float hours, float rate);
```

However you are trying to define a function with the same name with four parameters

```
void my_payroll::display_payslip(float gross, float hours, float rate, float              netpay) > this is the line that I'm getting the error on
{
//...
```

So the compiler issues the error.